# How to eager load (one to many) average and sort

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to get the average rating from 'Reviews' which is one to many with 'Recipes' and be able to sort with this. These are the following that I have tried so far but have had no success with.

```
// IN RECIPES
public function recipes() {
    return $this->hasMany('reviews');
}

public function avgRating() {
    return $this->reviews()
                ->selectRaw('avg(rating) as rating, recipe_id')
                ->groupBy('recipe_id');
}

public function avgRating() { // ALWAYS RETURNS EAGER LOAD ERROR AS IT'S A FLOAT, SO NOT USED
    return $this->reviews->avg('rating');
}

// IN CONTROLLER
$query = Recipe::select();
$query->withCount('reviews'); // GIVES ME COUNT OF REVIEWS WHICH I NEED

// PROVIDES avgRating: {recipeId, avgRating}, 
// WHICH I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SORT, AND WOULD PREFER AS avgRating: avgRating;
$query->with('avgRating');

// PROVIDES reviews: [{recipe_id, rating}]
// WHICH ISN'T AVERAGE SO NOT EASILY SORTABLE
$query->with('reviews:recipe_id,rating');
$query->paginate(8);
```

This would be my preferred output (simplified from paginate)

```
{
   recipes: {
       otherdata: x,
       avgRating: y,
       reviews_count: z,
   }
}
```

I don't necessarily want to have to append avgRating to this recipe all the time. Would it be possible to have a dynamic append?

EDIT: Since I'm not sure if there was ever a fix I found in stack overflow, here was the solution I eventually came up with. It might not be the most efficient solution out there but it works. If there is anyone that can improve it, I'd be most happy to update this as well.

```
$query->withCount([
    'reviews as reviewCount',
    'reviews as rating' => function($query) {
    $query->select(\DB::raw('coalesce(avg(rating),0)'));}
]);
$query->orderBy('rating', 'desc')
```

Comment: I recommend using `Laravel Collection` for this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-avg

Comment: Could easily turn the paginated data into a collection and average and sort from there, but it fails in some ways, mainly you can't sort by total rating unless you call all the recipes beforehand and find their relations